# Odd regex behaviour

Tags: java, regex, email

I have an annotation that validates email adresses coming into our REST API.
For the most parts it is doing a good job, however for some reason it breaks on emails containing a '+' sign, for example `mail+mail@mail.com`

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}")
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Email {

    String message() default "Not a valid email!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I have tested the regex on regex planet (http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) where it works and the regex matches the full mail address.

Just to validate that it is actually doing something I tried changing the regex to `.+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}` and that works.
I also tested `[A-Za-z0-9]+\\+[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}` to see if it could match specifically emails with a plus sign, but no luck.

So it seems as if the regex just can't match plus signs... or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your original regex [already works for me](https://regex101.com/r/UCx34U/1).  Can you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: I tested the regex at https://regex101.com/ and `mail+mail@mail.com` works just fine with the expression `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}` aswell. Are you sure the string you are matching is correctly encoded?

Comment: I will try my best to produce a "small" reproducible example. @OscardeLeeuw you might be onto something as it is a query param... might not be url decoded correctly

Comment: Note the plus symbol can be coded as `&#x002B;` or similar. Try adding `&;` to the start of the first character class.

Comment: currently on `[A-Za-z0-9._%+#&;-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}` with no luck, so if it url encoded, then it is not coded in a "traditional" manner...or I've written the regex incorrectly

Comment: do you know which Bean Validation provider (and version) is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending down an email such as `mail+mail@mail.com` as a query parameter, it will be coded on the way to the code. so in the servlet application it will look like `mail mail@mail.com` which seems rather unconventional.
This is tested with both jersey and javax.javaee-api as java ee implementations.

So the solution to this problem is adding a space to the regex.
`[A-Za-z0-9 ._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}`